# Data frame is showing different schema

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am creating data frame from an impala table as below.The schema o/p given below.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive._;
val hctx= new HiveContext(sc);
val dfSql = hctx.sql("select * from df2_rs.rs_trans_2 limit 1")
```

When i create the data frame using the underline parquet file of the table schema is different( There are string type in former and there are binary type in later for the same column ) . Schema is given below . Why there is a schema difference, where both are getting originally created from the same parquet file .

```
val df201606=hctx.parquetFile("/user/hive/warehouse/df2_rs.db/trans_2/month_id=201606");
df201606.printSchema;
```

The schema o/p is as follows:-
dfSql.printSchema

```
 root
     |-- supplier_id: short (nullable = true)
     |-- msa_seq_nbr: decimal(20,0) (nullable = true)
     |-- prod_surro_id: long (nullable = true)
     |-- mp_surro_id: long (nullable = true)
     |-- otlt_surro_id: integer (nullable = true)
     |-- payer_pln_surro_id: long (nullable = true)
     |-- btch_nbr: long (nullable = true)
     |-- store_nbr: string (nullable = true)
     |-- dspnsd_dt: timestamp (nullable = true)
     |-- btch_supplier_seq_nbr: long (nullable = true)
     |-- store_chnl_typ_cd: string (nullable = true)
     |-- typ_cd: string (nullable = true)
     |-- typ_cd_actn_cd: byte (nullable = true)
     |-- cmf_prod_nbr: string (nullable = true)
     |-- cmf_pack_nbr: string (nullable = true)
     |-- otlt_ctry_cd: string (nullable = true)
     |-- otlt_pstl_cd: string (nullable = true)
     |-- otlt_seq_nbr: string (nullable = true)
     |-- otlt_actn_cd: byte (nullable = true)
     |-- qty: decimal(18,3) (nullable = true)
     |-- qty_actn_cd: byte (nullable = true)
     |-- authd_rfll_nbr: byte (nullable = true)
     |-- authd_rfll_cd_actn_cd: byte (nullable = true)
     |-- pay_typ_cd: short (nullable = true)
     |-- pay_typ_cd_actn_cd: byte (nullable = true)
     |-- ddsupp_cnt: decimal(18,3) (nullable = true)
     |-- ddsupp_cnt_actn_cd: byte (nullable = true)
     |-- dspnsd_ndc: string (nullable = true)
     |-- dspnsd_ndc_actn_cd: byte (nullable = true)
     |-- mp_id: string (nullable = true)
     |-- mtch_cd: long (nullable = true)
     |-- usc_cd: string (nullable = true)
     |-- std_payer_id: string (nullable = true)
     |-- std_pln_id: string (nullable = true)
     |-- msk_payer_id: string (nullable = true)
     |-- msk_pln_id: string (nullable = true)
     |-- corrn_id: long (nullable = true)
     |-- enc_id: string (nullable = true)
     |-- pat_nbr: long (nullable = true)
     |-- dacon_qty: decimal(18,3) (nullable = true)
     |-- dacon_qty_actn_cd: byte (nullable = true)
     |-- dosg_qty: decimal(18,3) (nullable = true)
     |-- dosg_qty_actn_cd: byte (nullable = true)
     |-- cre_dt: timestamp (nullable = true)
     |-- std_pln_cd_ind: short (nullable = true)
     |-- supplier_pln_cd: string (nullable = true)
     |-- supplier_pln_id_actn_cd: short (nullable = true)
     |-- pcn: string (nullable = true)
     |-- bin_id: string (nullable = true)
     |-- grp_nbr: string (nullable = true)
     |-- pln_id_brdg_cd: short (nullable = true)
     |-- cust_prc_amt: decimal(18,3) (nullable = true)
     |-- strg: string (nullable = true)
     |-- store_cost_amt: decimal(18,3) (nullable = true)
     |-- store_cost_amt_actn_cd: string (nullable = true)
     |-- co_pay_amt: decimal(18,3) (nullable = true)
     |-- co_pay_cd: string (nullable = true)
     |-- pat_pharmy_owe_amt: decimal(18,3) (nullable = true)
     |-- pat_pay_ind: string (nullable = true)
     |-- pharmy_npi_id: string (nullable = true)
     |-- prscr_npi: string (nullable = true)
     |-- diag_icd9_cd: string (nullable = true)
     |-- orig_cd: string (nullable = true)
     |-- pat_zip3: string (nullable = true)
     |-- claim_id: long (nullable = true)
     |-- fill_nbr: integer (nullable = true)
     |-- data_use_qlfr_cd: string (nullable = true)
     |-- patient_id: long (nullable = true)
     |-- otlt_ncpdp_id: string (nullable = true)
     |-- mp_dea: string (nullable = true)
     |-- provider_id: long (nullable = true)
     |-- revsl_updt_dt: timestamp (nullable = true)
     |-- dup_updt_dt: timestamp (nullable = true)
     |-- corrn_updt_dt: timestamp (nullable = true)
     |-- supplier_pat_id: string (nullable = true)
     |-- diag_cd: string (nullable = true)
     |-- diag_vers_typ_id: byte (nullable = true)
     |-- month_id: integer (nullable = true)
```

The schema o/p is as follows:-
    df201606.printSchema :-

```
root
     |-- supplier_id: integer (nullable = true)
     |-- msa_seq_nbr: decimal(20,0) (nullable = true)
     |-- prod_surro_id: long (nullable = true)
     |-- mp_surro_id: long (nullable = true)
     |-- otlt_surro_id: integer (nullable = true)
     |-- payer_pln_surro_id: long (nullable = true)
     |-- lbtch_nbr: long (nullable = true)
     |-- store_nbr: binary (nullable = true)
     |-- dspnsd_dt: timestamp (nullable = true)
     |-- btch_supplier_seq_nbr: long (nullable = true)
     |-- store_chnl_typ_cd: binary (nullable = true)
     |-- typ_cd: binary (nullable = true)
     |-- typ_cd_actn_cd: integer (nullable = true)
     |-- cmf_prod_nbr: binary (nullable = true)
     |-- cmf_pack_nbr: binary (nullable = true)
     |-- otlt_ctry_cd: binary (nullable = true)
     |-- otlt_pstl_cd: binary (nullable = true)
     |-- otlt_seq_nbr: binary (nullable = true)
     |-- otlt_actn_cd: integer (nullable = true)
     |-- qty: decimal(18,3) (nullable = true)
     |-- qty_actn_cd: integer (nullable = true)
     |-- authd_rfll_nbr: integer (nullable = true)
     |-- authd_rfll_cd_actn_cd: integer (nullable = true)
     |-- pay_typ_cd: integer (nullable = true)
     |-- pay_typ_cd_actn_cd: integer (nullable = true)
     |-- ddsupp_cnt: decimal(18,3) (nullable = true)
     |-- ddsupp_cnt_actn_cd: integer (nullable = true)
     |-- dspnsd_ndc: binary (nullable = true)
     |-- dspnsd_ndc_actn_cd: integer (nullable = true)
     |-- mp_id: binary (nullable = true)
     |-- mtch_cd: long (nullable = true)
     |-- usc_cd: binary (nullable = true)
     |-- std_payer_id: binary (nullable = true)
     |-- std_pln_id: binary (nullable = true)
     |-- msk_payer_id: binary (nullable = true)
     |-- msk_pln_id: binary (nullable = true)
     |-- corrn_id: long (nullable = true)
     |-- enc_id: binary (nullable = true)
     |-- pat_nbr: long (nullable = true)
     |-- dacon_qty: decimal(18,3) (nullable = true)
     |-- dacon_qty_actn_cd: integer (nullable = true)
     |-- dosg_qty: decimal(18,3) (nullable = true)
     |-- dosg_qty_actn_cd: integer (nullable = true)
     |-- cre_dt: timestamp (nullable = true)
     |-- std_pln_cd_ind: integer (nullable = true)
     |-- supplier_pln_cd: binary (nullable = true)
     |-- supplier_pln_id_actn_cd: integer (nullable = true)
     |-- pcn: binary (nullable = true)
     |-- bin_id: binary (nullable = true)
     |-- grp_nbr: binary (nullable = true)
     |-- pln_id_brdg_cd: integer (nullable = true)
     |-- cust_prc_amt: decimal(18,3) (nullable = true)
     |-- strg: binary (nullable = true)
     |-- store_cost_amt: decimal(18,3) (nullable = true)
     |-- store_cost_amt_actn_cd: binary (nullable = true)
     |-- co_pay_amt: decimal(18,3) (nullable = true)
     |-- co_pay_cd: binary (nullable = true)
     |-- pat_pharmy_owe_amt: decimal(18,3) (nullable = true)
     |-- pat_pay_ind: binary (nullable = true)
     |-- lpharmy_npi_id: binary (nullable = true)
     |-- prscr_npi: binary (nullable = true)
     |-- diag_icd9_cd: binary (nullable = true)
     |-- orig_cd: binary (nullable = true)
     |-- pat_zip3: binary (nullable = true)
     |-- claim_id: long (nullable = true)
     |-- fill_nbr: integer (nullable = true)
     |-- data_use_qlfr_cd: binary (nullable = true)
     |-- patient_id: long (nullable = true)
     |-- otlt_ncpdp_id: binary (nullable = true)
     |-- mp_dea: binary (nullable = true)
     |-- provider_id: long (nullable = true)
     |-- revsl_updt_dt: timestamp (nullable = true)
     |-- dup_updt_dt: timestamp (nullable = true)
     |-- corrn_updt_dt: timestamp (nullable = true)
     |-- supplier_pat_id: binary (nullable = true)
     |-- diag_cd: binary (nullable = true)
     |-- diag_vers_typ_id: integer (nullable = true)
```

Comment: I think you should also mention the column names when asking to compare schema as it saves time and effort for others

Comment: I think the possible reason is that create table statement in Hive is different from the actual parquet schema

Comment: so , if u use parquet-tools to check schema , i think u will get schema similar to df201606.printSchema , however , if you see the show create table in hive , then schema will come similar to dfSql.printSchema . This is because when using hivecontext to access a table , i think it picks up the schema from metastore instead of actual parquet file